# Why innerHTML doesnt work correctly in for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, asynchronous, innerhtml

What is the difference of this

```
var content= "";

for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    content = content + '<fieldset>' + '<legend>Grup ' + i + '</legend>';

    for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        content = content + '<div class="item"> item ' + i + ',' + j + '</div>';
    }

    content = content + '</fieldset>';
}

div.innerHTML = content;
```

and this

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<fieldset>' + '<legend>Grup ' + i + '</legend>';

    for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<div class="item"> item ' + i + ',' + j + '</div>';
    }

    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '</fieldset>';      
}
```

I tried all the two ways. But the second one doesnt work as i expected. When i use div.innerHTML in for loop, the inner loop works after < /fieldset > and output is like :

```
<fieldset> 
    <legend>Grup x</legend>
</fieldset>
<div class="item"> item 1,1 </div>
<div class="item"> item 1,2 </div>
....
```

You can test the issue at http://mutlakyazilim.com/test.html. Why are they different, anybody has idea ?

Comment: the first one's preferrable. every time you modify the div's innerhtml, you're forcing the browser to re-render the div. best to build your html as a string (`content`), then stuff it into the DOM all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [`innerHTML`](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#innerhtml) is a special property of HTML elements that has special behaviour when you get or set it.

When you get it (by doing `var x = el.innerHTML` for example), a serialization algorithm is run which converts the DOM sub-tree into HTML text.

When you set it (by doing `el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + '<html code>'` for example), the text is sent through a html parser and set as the children if that element.

---

In your case, you are doing stuff like:

```
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<fieldset>';
```

Assuming `div.innerHTML` is initially empty, the code resolves to:

```
div.innerHTML = '<fieldset>';
```

this actually sends it through a parser, which generates html equivalent to:

```
<fieldset></fieldset>
```

which makes this code different.

---

A simple test you can run to confirm this is:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<div>';
console.log(document.body.innerHTML); // should be `<div></div>`
```

Comment: Thanks for the best answer first. And with the same reason, i cant see '</fieldset>' tag which i have added manually..

Answer (score 0):

`content` is initially empty, but the `innerHTML` of `div` is not.

You could change this line to get the desired result:

```
div.innerHTML += content;
//            ^ here
```

Comment: Thx for answer first.

I have made empty innerHTML with 'div.innerHTML=""' and replaced all 'div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + ...' to 'div.innerHTML += ...' but the result didnt change.